# Site Migration to WordPress: Handling Feeds

Tags: rss, migration

I'm moving a site hosted with another blogging system to WordPress.  This site's RSS feed is hosted at the URL

```
http://example.com/home?format=rss
```

I want to ensure that users with this RSS Feed in their feed readers continue to get updates when I move to WordPress.

Is there a standard way in stock WordPress to handle this?

If not, is there a standard plugin to handle this?

If not, how **are** people handling this? Apache redirects?  Something else?

Comment: Alan, I'm curious, this question was posed over a year ago.  Did you figure out a solution?  I'm dealing with the same issue on my own blog and am hoping there's a non-plugin solution you may have come across...

Comment: @BJHoffpauir I never found a no brainier solution so I probably did this manually with Apache redirects.

Comment: Was hoping to find another possible solution...we're trying to get rid of .htaccess files strewn about in WP and Magento to improve performance (didn't learn until recently that when enabled, apache checks all directories up the tree for files...kind of a non-brainer though I understand the design decision, hate the performance impact...)  this was a while back, so I understand if you don't recall, but do you know if the rules you used could work in a site-level .conf file as well as a .htaccess?  That would at least help with performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with a [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). I won't recommend touching .htaccess file without expert knowledge.

Add New Redirection like this:

```
Source URL: /home?format=rss
Target URL: http://YOUR_WORDPRESS_SITE/feed
```

Save the settings.